# Am I missing solutions by solving this trigonometric equation like this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

This is a quite elementary and simplified equation, but I am afraid that I am missing some of the solutions.

I have

$ t = t\cos\theta - n \sin\theta$.

What I had done before to solve it was the following,

$t^2 = t^2 \cos^2 \theta - 2tn\cos\theta\sin\theta + n^2\sin^2\theta\\$,

$t^2 \sin^2\theta = -2tn\cos\theta\sin\theta + n^2 \sin^2\theta$,

$(t^2-n^2)\sin^2\theta = -2tn\cos\theta\sin\theta$,

$(t^2-n^2)\tan\theta = -2tn$

In this very last step, I would just divide by $(t^2-n^2)$ and solve for $\theta$ it being the inverse tangent of what precedes in the equation. However, I am afraid that I am leaving out potential solutions where $(t^2-n^2) = 0$ or worse when $-2tn/(t^2-n^2)$ may be undefined (as $0/0$).

I know that from the initial equation, I can do the following,
$ t(1 - \cos\theta) = -n\sin\theta$.

Here I am also afraid of dividing by n or t, because they can individually be zero. In this instance where $n=0$,
I get that $t=0$, and $\cos\theta = 1$. But I am not sure if I am leaving out other possibilities.

Comment: any time you divide by a variable expression,  just take the case that the thing you are dividing by is 0 as a separate case.  The other cases you have are when $n=\pm t$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem was dividing by $\sin\theta\cos\theta,$ where those could be zero. So handle the cases when $\sin\theta=0$ and $\cos\theta=0$ first.

From:$$(t^2-n^2)\sin^2\theta =-2tn\cos\theta\sin\theta\tag1$$
If $\sin\theta=0,$ these are always equal.

But the earlier squaring added the case when $\sin\theta=0,\cos\theta=-1.$

When $\cos \theta=0,$ you need $t^2-n^2=0,$ which means $n=\pm t.$ Again, squaring both sides added cases, here adding the case where $\sin \theta =\pm 1,$ $n=t\sin\theta.$

When $\sin\theta\cos\theta\neq 0,$ you can divide by it, and then $\tan\theta$ is defined and not equal to  $0.$

If $t^2-n^2=0,$ this equation has a solution only when $n=t=0.$ Then any $\theta$ works.

---

The easier solution is to never square and convert the equation to:

$$\tan(\theta/2)=\frac{1-\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}=-\frac nt$$ Handle the cases  where $\sin(\theta)=0$ and $t=0$ seperately.

Comment: "But the earlier squaring added the case when sinθ=0,cosθ=−1." Can you elaborate on why this is the case? I am not getting how these arise from squaring.

Comment: If you are trying to solve $A=B,$ and you square both sides, then solutions to $A^2=B^2$ includes  solutions to $A=B$ and solutions to $A=-B.$  @Madlad

Comment: Oh wow you are right! Thank you for your patience, and clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

You can only divide by an expression if it cannot be zero. So when you need to do such operation, always consider the case when that expression is zero. For example, your equation can be solved like this: $$\begin{align}t(1 - \cos\theta) &= -n\sin\theta \implies \\t&=\frac{-n\sin\theta}{1 - \cos\theta}\\&=\frac{-2n \sin{\theta/2}\cos{\theta/2}}{2\sin^2{\theta/2}}\\&=-n\cot{\theta/2}\end{align}$$
Here we divided by $1-\cos \theta$ so we need to consider case $1-\cos \theta=0$. In this case the original equation becomes an identity $t=t$ so you are losing solutions for $\theta$ if you do not consider this case.